# how to save state of my button with share preferences?

Tags: java, android

In my application when user click back , I make an alert dialog that included 2 buttons. first button is Exit that allow user to exit the application.
the second button is 5 star that allow user to rate me in the market.
it works correctly.
but the problem is that when I kill the application and I run it again, this process repeat. and I want if the user rate me before , I don't show the 5 star button to user again.
how can I save my state button in it?
I know that I must share preferences , but how?

```
    int star = 0;
    public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();

    if(id == R.id.button1 && stringListCounter <lines.size() - 1) {
        stringListCounter++;
    } else if (id == R.id.button2 && stringListCounter > 0) {
        stringListCounter--;
    }
    txtQuestion.setText(lines.get(stringListCounter));
}
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(QuizActivity.this);

    alertDialog.setTitle("please rate us");

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("5star", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_EDIT,
                    Uri.parse("http://cafebazaar.ir/app/my package name/?l=fa"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
            star ++;


        }
    });


    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent1.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent1);

        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();



}
```

here my star value is 0. when user rate me , the value of star become 1 . I
want save the my star value to 1 that this process don't repeat again.
please help

Answer (score 0):

First Of Save Preferences

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt("KeyValue", newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

Read from Shared Preferences

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger("KeyValue");
```

after get preference easily check condition

Comment: if error with getActivity() then replace with getApplicationContext() method

Answer (score 0):

you can create one method in shared preferences that will give your app state means when user is clicking on 5 start on that time you have to set the app state 1. and next time before calling this

```
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("5star", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_EDIT,
                Uri.parse("http://cafebazaar.ir/app/my package name/?l=fa"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
        star ++;


    }
});
```

apply if condition and check the state of the app in shared preference means if state is 1 then don't allow to execute this functionality else allow.

Comment: can you help me more , how can I do this?

Comment: create one seperate class and add this functionality and call the setAppState method from from which you want to set the app state:-       public static SharedPreferences getSharedprefarences(Context c) {return c.getSharedPreferences("your file name", 0);//0 means mode_private
 }
public static void setAppState(boolean value, Context c) {
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedprefarences(c).edit();
  editor.putBoolean("AppState", value);
  editor.commit();
 }
  public static boolean getAppState(Context c) {
        return getSharedprefarences(c).getBoolean("AppState", false);
}